# Check how many <li> there are in a <ul> with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Following my code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="ul_o">
<li>v1</li>
<li>v2</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("ul_o").getElementsByClassName("LI").length);
```

Why the in the console there are the number 0 instead of 2?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Give - `document.getElementById("ul_o").getElementsByTagName("li").length`

To have a wider answer that ensures the `dom` is ready for being accessed and updated by `JS`, we can make use of the [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange) event something like in html5 -

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="ul_o">
<li>v1</li>
<li>v2</li>
<li>v3</li>
</ul>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<h4><code>ul</code> with <i>ul_o</i> has '+document.getElementById("ul_o").getElementsByTagName("li").length +' <code>li</code> Tags</h4>';
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ishankdubey/muvw304k/)

Comment: Forget the fiddle. Its a straightforward answer and the OP should mark this as solution bcos yours was the first answer

Comment: @Ishank Dubey , You forgot to mention here: above method will work only if DOM is loaded

Comment: true @Vickey, DOM must be loaded.

Answer (score 9):

Just use:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#ul_o li").length
```

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByClassName` uses the class attribute to identify tags. You should use `getElementsByTagName("li")`

```
console.log(document.getElementById("ul_o").getElementsByTagName("li").length)
```

Answer (score 4):

This table is self-explanatory :-)

| DOM Element | DOM method | DOM method result type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `<li id="li"></li>` | `getElementById('li')` | `#li` |
| `<li class="li"></li>` | `getElementsByClassName('li')` | `[.li, ..., .li]` |
| `<li></li>` | `getElementsByTagName('li')` | `[li, ..., li]` |

Answer (score 2):

You have used the following code in your JS

`console.log(document.getElementById('ul_o').getElementsByClassName('li').length);`

You need to understand that <li> is a tag name and not a class name. Class name are attributes assigned to tags. For example,

`console.log(document.getElementById('ul_o').getElementsByTagName('li').length);`

With name ClassName replaced by TagName your code will count the number of <li>
present in the <ul>

Answer (score 2):

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("ul_o");
console.log(elem.childElementCount);
```

```html
<ul id="ul_o">
<li>v1</li>
<li>v2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id="ul_o">
<li class="my-class">v1</li>
<li class="my-class">v2</li>
</ul>

console.log(document.getElementById("ul_o").getElementsByClassName("my-class").length);
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
 console.log(document.getElementById("ul_o").getElementsByTagName("LI").length);
```

**document.getElementsByTagName**

> The getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of an elements's child elements with the specified tagname, as a NodeList object.

**document.getElementsByClassName**

> Returns a set of elements which have all the given class names

Comment: Why did u use `LI` instead of `li`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `querySelectorAll` to get the length of elements but make sure you call all these methods after DOM is loaded

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log(document.getElementById("ul_o").querySelectorAll("li").length);
}, false);
```